# installing yuidoc under windows 7

Tags: windows, node.js, npm

I'm trying to get yuidoc running under windows 7... and failing.
Now I'm a nodejs noob so maybe I'm doing something wrong.

I've installed the node-v0.6.19.msi from nodejs.org (got 'hello world' running so that's good)
Then I tried installing yuidoc via npm (as described here http://yui.github.com/yuidoc/)

The npm install seems to work (lots of http GET and no big red ERR!s).
Next I tried 'node yuidoc .' but that throws a 'cannot find module'.

The node msi default install folder is C:\Program Files\nodejs\
while the npm installs yuidoc to C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yuidocjs

<del>Weirdly, the npm install only created some empty folders. What am I doing wrong?</del>
Ah sorry, that was my bad trying to reinstall yuidoc with npm (it errored and cleared the folders).

I now seem to have yuidoc correctly installed (lot's of files in ..node_modules\yuidocjs). But trying to run it from node.js still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Ah it was just me being a nodejs noob. I thought I needed to run everything from within node (also tried running npm that way at first too).

Simply running yuidoc directly from command prompt does the trick.

Comment: Thanks for answering yourself. It help me here. Cheers!

Comment: Bro can u help me,I installed as u did, then I run yuidoc from windows 7 command prompt but it cant find the command as "command not found" error

Comment: What I didn't realize is that npm is a Windows command. Once I figured that out, it worked fine for me.